# How can you make Mootools drag and drop that is touch compatible?

Tags: drag-and-drop, mootools, touch, draggable

I am building a drag and drop interface using Mootools .draggable() method. It's working great except that it does not work on touch devices which is important for it to do. Is there a way to make .draggable() touch compatible?

Answer (score 1):

have you read this answer? [Drag with mootools on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588576/drag-with-mootools-on-mobile)

it does not seem to work too well with droid tablets. see http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/kLVJy/ - dragging is choppy and drops it too early. might be better on ios, not sure. something to build on anyway

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitar said, read the answer [Drag with mootools on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588576/drag-with-mootools-on-mobile).

The provided answer though is buggy, and works bad in both android and ios at the time of this writing.

Speaking about android the problem is due to a bug, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5491.

The workaround consists in calling

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in the touchmove callback. Such workaround works well in my case for both android and ios.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abidibo/aWJ8S/